# Inserting a Relation into Neo4j using MERGE or MATCH runs forever

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am experimenting with Neo4j using a simple dataset of Locations. A location can have a relation to another relation.
a:Location - [rel] - b:Location

I already have the locations in the database (roughly 700.000+ Location entries)

Now I wanted to add the relation data (170M Edges), but I wanted to experiment with the import logic with a smaller set first, so I basically picked 2 nodes that are in the set and tried to create a relationship as follows.

```
MERGE p =(a:Location {locationid: 3616})-[w:WikiLink]->(b:Location {locationid: 467501})
RETURN p;
```

and also tried the approach directly from the docu

```
MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person)
WHERE a.name = 'Node A' AND b.name = 'Node B'
CREATE (a)-[r:RELTYPE { name : a.name + '<->' + b.name }]->(b)
RETURN r
```

I tried using a directional merge, undirectional merge, etc. etc. I basically tried multiple variants of the above queries and the result is: They run forever, seeming to no complete even after 15 minutes. Which is very odd.

```
Indexes
  ON :Location(locationid) ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 

Constraints
  ON (location:Location) ASSERT location.locationid IS UNIQUE
```

This is what I am currently using:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///edgelist.csv' AS line WITH line
MATCH (a:Location {locationid: toInt(line.locationidone)}), (b:Location {locationid: toInt(line.locationidtwo)})
MERGE (a)-[w:WikiLink {weight: toFloat(line.edgeweight)}]-(b)
RETURN COUNT(w);
```

If you look at the terminal output below you can see Neo4j reports 258ms query execution time, the realtime is however somewhat above that. This query already takes a few seconds too much in my opinion (The machine this runs on has 48GB RAM, 16 Cores and is relatively new).
I am currently running this query with `LIMIT 1000` (before it was `LIMIT 1`) but the script is already running for a few minutes. I wonder if I have to switch from MERGE to CREATE. The problem is, I cannot understand the callgraph that `EXPLAIN` gives me in order to determine the bottleneck.

```
time /usr/local/neo4j/bin/neo4j-shell -file import-relations.cql 
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| p                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [Node[758609]{title:"Tehran",locationid:3616,locationlabel:"NIL"},:WikiLink[9422418]{weight:1.2282325516616477E-7},Node[917147]{title:"Khorugh",locationid:467501,locationlabel:"city"}] |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row
Relationships created: 1
Properties set: 1
258 ms

real    0m1.417s
user    0m1.497s
sys 0m0.158s
```

[image: EXPLAIN of the query]

Comment: Which version of `neo4j` do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't:

```
create constraint on loc:Location assert loc.locationid is unique;
```

Then find both nodes, and create the releationship.

```
MATCH (a:Location {locationid: 3616}),(b:Location {locationid: 467501})
MERGE p = (a)-[w:WikiLink]->(b)
RETURN p;
```

or if the locations don't exist yet:

```
MERGE (a:Location {locationid: 3616})
MERGE (b:Location {locationid: 467501})
MERGE p = (a)-[w:WikiLink]->(b)
RETURN p;
```

You should also use parameters if you do that from a program.

Comment: I updated my question to give you more information. I think if you look at my query, I already use the approach you suggested, you might correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you indexed the `Location` nodes on `locationid`?

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Location(locationid)
```

I had a similar problem adding edges to a graph and indexing the nodes led to the linking running over 150x faster.

If the nodes aren't indexed `neo4j` will do a serial search for the two nodes to link together.

Comment: yes I that's what I did. I have a unique constraint and index on that field.

Answer (score 0):

`USING PERIODIC COMMIT <value>`:

Specifies number of records(rows) to be commited in a transaction. Since you have high RAM, it is good to use value that is greater than 100000. This will reduce the number of transactions committed and might further reduce the overall time.